# avg, biggest and sum in unknown sized array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

Im trying to write a console application in c++ that will let the user input a series of numbers and the program should get the sum of all numbers, the average number, the largest and the second largest number.
For example:

Enter a couple of numbers : 10 12 -5 20 -2 15 0

Sum = 50

Average value = 8.3

Largest number = 20

Second largest = 15

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std; 
int main( )
{


int a[5];

cout << "We are going to find the max value"<< endl;
int x;

    for (x=0; x<5; x++)
    {
        cout<<"insert values"<<x+1<<endl;
            cin>>a[x];
    }
    int max;
    int min;
    max = a[0];
    min = a[0];
    int e=0;
        while (e<5)
        {
            if (a[e]>max)
            {
                max = a[e];
            }

            e++;
        }
        cout<<"Max value in the array is.."<<max<<endl;

    getch();
    return 0;
 }
```

This is my progress so far.
Although, I have some concerns.
How do I let the user input the numbers like in the example and store them in a array with unknown size?

I'll try to figure out a way to count the avg, sum and second largest while waiting for this answer :)

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to learn about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), and learn a little about [standard C++ algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Comment: Technically, no vector is required since all values can be calculated on the fly.

Comment: @Jasper Good point.  I'm not sure if that's easier than `std::vector`, but it's certainly easier than any other solution (which more or less requires reimplementing `std::vector`).

Answer (score 1):

To input an unknown number of elements, you use `std::vector`, inputting
until the user tells you to stop, typically by inputting an end of file:

```
std::vector<int> values;
int i;
while ( std::cin >> i ) {
    values.push_back( i ) ;
}
```

If you're looking for some other type a signal for the end, you'll
probably have to read line by line, checking whether the line contains
your end criteron, and then use `std::istringstream` to parse the
integer.

For the rest: it may not correspond to the goal of the exercise, but
the standard library has a couple of functions which could make things
significantly simpler: `std::max_element`, for example, or
`std::accumulate`.  And `<conio.h>` is not very portable, and is
deprecated on the systems which do support it.

Comment: Thanks!  Will read more about it. The numbers entered should end with a 0.

Comment: @MarkBear34 A `0` value is the sentinel for the end.  In that case, it's easy.  The loop just becomes `while ( std::cin >> i && i != 0 )...`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use `std::vector`, you might want to learn about [dynamic memory allocation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/).

```
int *a = new int[size];
```

Comment: Handling an unknown number of elements without `std::vector` is decidedly non-trivial; a simple `new` requires knowing the number of elements before hand.  (Of course, if he's dealing with manual user input, he can just declare something like `int a[1000000];`; no user is going to manually input more than a million values, and that's not really a lot of memory on a modern machine.)